# adding a listener to a listField in BlackBerry

Tags: listview, blackberry, listener, keylistener

I am working on BB OS v5.0, 8520. I have managed to get the list to appear on the screen. I am using a String Array and adding it into a Vector. Now I want to find out onclick, which is the item that is clicked and accordingly perform some operation. for the time being lets just say i want to throw an alert. any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `ListField` you should override `navigationClick(int status, int time)`. Then inside of the `navigationClick()` get the selected item index via `ListField.getSelectedIndex()` and do what ever you need with it.

Note, you don't need to override `touchEvent(TouchEvent message)`, because `navigationClick()` is called by BB framework regardless of whether the click event is originated by a touch-screen event or a trackball(pad) event. So the code will work for any screen type.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the strings and making them clickable?

You could extend [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html), override the trackwheelClick or touchEvent methods and do what you want there.